# How to loop, search and concatenate string in with cursor in TSQL?

Tags: t-sql, while-loop

I have this set of data

```
psrid   parent_psrid    description
1   NULL    Work Management
2   1   Asset Maintenance
3   2   Code
4   3   asset type code
5   3   asset class code
6   3   asset class code - common rate type code
7   3   asset type code - asset status code
8   3   asset material class code - common rate type code
9   3   external interface code
10  2   Asset
11  10  asset
12  10  asset attachment
13  10  asset - common rate type code
14  2   Warranty
15  14  asset warranty attachment
16  1   CRM
17  16  Request
18  17  request
19  16  Code
20  19  crm request type code - crm task type code
21  19  task category code
22  19  request category code
23  19  request type code
24  19  task type code
```

I want to create a stored procedure to concatenate description of selected `psrid` with descriptions of all other rows that have `parent_psrid` which matches the `psrid` from previous row, so on and so forth until the parent `psrid` is null. Please note, it will only look and concatenate descriptions with the rows above it (`psrid` is primary key and sorted).

This is like a zic-zac mapping. For example, if we start at psrid 10 and parent_psrid is 2 as below picture, then the final concatenated string would be Work Management > Asset Maintenance > Asset

[image]

I have got to this far but I don't know what to do next.

```
-- Declare a variables
DECLARE @in_psrid int = 10,
        @psrid nvarchar(255),
        @spsone_datasecurity_model_parent_psrid nvarchar(255),
        @object_description nvarchar(255)

-- Declare a variable of type TABLE. It will be used as a temporary table.
DECLARE @myTable TABLE (
    [psrid]        int,
    [spsone_datasecurity_model_parent_psrid]   int,
    [object_description]   nvarchar(255)
)

-- Insert required data in the variable of type TABLE
INSERT INTO @myTable
SELECT [psrid], [spsone_datasecurity_model_parent_psrid], [object_description]
FROM [IcjisTest].[dbo].[Book2]

-- Declare cursor
DECLARE cur_psrid CURSOR
    FOR SELECT [psrid], [spsone_datasecurity_model_parent_psrid], [object_description]
    FROM @myTable
    WHERE [psrid] = @in_psrid;

OPEN cur_psrid;

FETCH NEXT FROM cur_psrid INTO 
    @psrid, 
    @spsone_datasecurity_model_parent_psrid,
    @object_description;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        PRINT @psrid + @spsone_datasecurity_model_parent_psrid + @object_description;
        FETCH NEXT FROM cur_psrid INTO 
            @psrid, 
            @spsone_datasecurity_model_parent_psrid,
            @object_description;
    END;

    CLOSE cur_psrid;

DEALLOCATE cur_psrid;
```

Please help! Thank you.

Comment: Why do you want to do it `with cursor` ?

Comment: SQL is a set based language. It doesn't really need cursors, they're there for *very* limited scenarios. You have two questions 1) how to walk the hierarchy. The answer to that is to use a recursive CTE. 2) How to aggregate strings. The answer in SQL Server 2017 is to use `STRING_AGG`. In earlier versions there are ways to aggregate strings using `FOR XML` and other tricks

Comment: @Squirrel no particular reason. I am basically experimenting. Please let me know if there is a better approach. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any time you think "I should loop" in a database you should immediately think "but there must be a better "set" approach to solving this".

A [recursive CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#guidelines-for-defining-and-using-recursive-common-table-expressions) is the better "set" approach to solving this. Check out Example D in that link in the "Examples" section of the page.

```
WITH buildstring As
(
    /*
     * Recursive Seed - Starting point of recursive lookup
     */
    SELECT psrid, parent_psrid, description, 1 as depth
    FROM yourtable
    WHERE psrid = 10

    UNION ALL

    /* 
     * Recursive Member - The part that loops until the join(s) fail
     * Note that we refer to the CTE itself (buildstring) in the 
     * FROM clause, which is what causes the recursiveness. 
     */
    SELECT
        yourtable.psrid,
        yourtable.parent_psrid,
        buildstring.description + " " + yourtable.description,
        buildstring.depth + 1
    FROM buildstring
        INNER JOIN yourtable 
            ON buildstring.parent_psrid = yourtable.psrid
    WHERE depth < 20 --Just in case you get into an infinite cycle
          
)
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT description, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY depth DESC) as rn FROM buildstring) depth
WHERE rn = 1 --Get the last record created by the recursive CTE
```

That should get you in the ballpark. You'll most likely want to tweak that a bit to get whatever output you are looking for, but that should spit out a description with all parent descriptions of `psrid` of `10`.

Comment: I got an error "Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "object_description" of recursive query "buildstring"." but I casted object_description to the same data type and length and it worked. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Great! Glad to hear that it worked for you. I know some RDBMSs are picky about casting between the top and bottom of the recursive CTEs. It's been a while since I worked with tsql and couldn't remember if it was a picky one.